# Changing underscores to hyphens in URLs Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I need to change underscores to hyphens for SEO of our to-do checklist page in Ruby on Rails project. The relevant line in routes.rb file is below:

```
get 'to_do' => 'current_to_do_items#landing', :as => :to_do
```

I tried to change it to:

```
get 'to-do' => 'current_to_do_items#landing', :as => :to-do
```

but in this part "as => :to-do" do is detected as a key word,
could you please advise how should I name it?

Comment: try `as: "to-do"`, I don't think hyphens are legitimate in Ruby symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:as` option generates urls helpers, even if you change it to `as: "to-do"` your helpers will [not](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.2/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1849) change: `to_do_path` and `to_do_url`. All of these generate the same route and helpers:

```rb
# technically, you don't need :as option here, because it's the same as path
get "to-do", to: "current_to_do_items#landing"

get "to-do", to: "current_to_do_items#landing", as: :to_do
get "to-do", to: "current_to_do_items#landing", as: "to-do"
```

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match*

---

You can quote symbols if you have characters other than letters and underscores:

```rb
{ "to-do": :"to do!" }
```

Answer (score 1):

use a new rails syntax rather than using old syntax

```
get 'to-do', to: 'current_to_do_items#landing', as: 'to-do'
```